# How can I unlock a file without closing the file handle?

Tags: windows, file-unlocking

When I'm downloading a video file with Google Chrome, the file is locked and cannot be opened by media players. I want to be able to play the file while it's being downloaded. The video bitrate is lower than my Internet bandwidth so it wouldn't be a problem.

Popular unlockers work by closing file handles, which would interrupt the download. How can I remove the read-lock without closing the file handle? Can I replace the read-lock with a write-lock?

Comment: Just to let people know, Google Chrome 16 no longer have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a link to the file using `mklink` at the command prompt. I haven't used it in your particular scenario but have used it to successfully to gain access to a browser's temporary cache files whilst locked.

Comment: Works perfectly!